# How to fix linking issue in cmake for open ni2

Tags: build, cmake, shared-libraries, fedora, openni

I have a code which uses the header file OpenNI.h and I am using CMake. Every time I run make I get error:

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable oniproject
CMakeFiles/oniproject.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `openni::VideoStream::start()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6openni11VideoStream5startEv[_ZN6openni11VideoStream5startEv]+0x31):>undefined reference to `oniStreamStart'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like

```
find_library(OPENNI2_LIBRARY
    NAMES OpenNI
    PATHS /usr/lib64
)
find_path (OPENNI2_INCLUDES OpenNI.h
    /usr/local/src/OpenNI2/Include 
)

include_directories(${OPENNI2_INCLUDES})
# practice
add_executable(oniproject 
    main.cpp
    Viewer.cpp
    Viewer.h
)
target_link_libraries(oniproject ${OPENNI2_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(oniproject ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} )
include_directories (${LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${LIBUSB_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?